# Rstudio Connections tab doesn't help me refer to an object name in code

Tags: r, odbc

I can **see** an object but I can't refer to it in code:

```
library(odbc)
library(DBI)
library(tidyverse)
library(readr)

con <- dbConnect(odbc::odbc(),
                 driver = "libtdsodbc.so",
                 database = "AdventureWorks2012",
                 uid = "sqlfamily",
                 pwd = "sqlf@m1ly",
                 Server = "mhknbn2kdz.database.windows.net",
                 port = 1433)

# dbListTables(con)  # commented out because the output is long...

Department <- dbReadTable(con, "AdventureWorks2012.HumanResources.Department")
```

Here is what I see in Rstudio:

[image: Rstudio connections tab showing the table]

And there is data for viewing as well:

[image]

BUT, the following command attempts generate errors:

```
> person <- dbReadTable(con, "Person.Person")
Error: <SQL> 'SELECT * FROM "Person.Person"'
  nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1587: 42S02: [FreeTDS][SQL Server]Invalid object name 'Person.Person'. 
> person <- dbReadTable(con, "Person.Contact")
Error: <SQL> 'SELECT * FROM "Person.Contact"'
  nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1587: 42S02: [FreeTDS][SQL Server]Invalid object name 'Person.Contact'. 
> person <- dbReadTable(con, "Sales.SalesPerson")
Error: <SQL> 'SELECT * FROM "Sales.SalesPerson"'
  nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1587: 42S02: [FreeTDS][SQL Server]Invalid object name 'Sales.SalesPerson'. 
> person <- dbReadTable(con, "Sales.Customer")
Error: <SQL> 'SELECT * FROM "Sales.Customer"'
  nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1587: 42S02: [FreeTDS][SQL Server]Invalid object name 'Sales.Customer'. 
> Department <- dbReadTable(con, "AdventureWorks2012.HumanResources.Department")
Error: <SQL> 'SELECT * FROM "AdventureWorks2012.HumanResources.Department"'
  nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1587: 42S02: [FreeTDS][SQL Server]Invalid object name 'AdventureWorks2012.HumanResources.Department'. 
>
```

How am I supposed to refer to that table?  I'd like to use dplyr but would settle for writing straight SQL query.

Comment: Have you tried `dbReadTable(con, Id(schema = "Person", table = "Person"))`?

Comment: John did you ever figure this out? I'm stuck on the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Scarabee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6656269/scarabee) suggests, this works:

> dbReadTable(con, Id(schema = "Person", table = "Person"))